# How to use the results of a SQL Server stored procedure (scheduled to run weekly) for trending the data over time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, data-warehouse

I have a stored procedure in a SQL Server 2008 database that returns a set of values pulled from various different tables such as the following. I run the stored procedure as shown below, without any parameters.

```
EXEC [Data].[dbo].[sp_Usage]
```

Each row shows the product usage data such as

- Last Login
- No.of times used last month
- last 3 months
- last  6 months
- App Version

for each unique `AccountId`

I want to run this stored procedure automatically every month/week and store the corresponding results in the database, without erasing the last week/month's data.

I plan to use this data over time to do data trending.

How should I execute this plan?

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated

Cheers!
Shiny

Answer (score 3):

So your stored procedure presumably has a `SELECT (list of columns) .....` inside it, right?

Why not change that to something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourBigTable(ExecutionDateTime, ...other columns here.....)
   SELECT
       GETDATE(),   -- get current date/time
       (list of other columns)
   FROM .......
```

Just basically make the stored procedure run the `INSERT` into your target table directly. That would seem like the easiest way to go from my point of view.

Otherwise, you need to insert the data returned from the stored procedure into a temporary table, and then insert that temporary table's data, along with the execution date/time, into your target table.

Comment: Thanks for a starting thought. But could you please tell how to structure the YourBigTable, that is the destination table that holds another table (result of the stored proc)?

Comment: @Shiny: well, that target table needs to hold all the columns you want to track - plus the date/timestamp of when the data was determined.